# Partial Residual Plots and Interactions

Tags: regression, data-visualization, interaction, residuals

In linear regression, we can use partial residual plots to decide on potentially nonlinear transformations of a quantitative covariate $X_j$.

They plot the residuals $r_{Y|X_{-j}}$ on the y-axis and $r_{X_j|X_{-j}}$ on the x-axis, where $X_{-j}$ is the design matrix with the column $j$ removed.

I have done this for a covariate $X_j$ that I expect to interact with a binary covariate $X_l$ which has values in $\{0,1\}$.

I then produce two (colored) clouds of partial residuals, one for which $X_l=1$ and one for which $X_l=0$. If they have different slopes (or different patterns in general), I conclude that an interaction should be included. Is this a reasonable approach?